# setup neccessary latex items on windows

Tags: packages, installing

Assume that I have a fresh windows 7 and I want to setup Latex on my machine. I would need some basic software, Latex editor, bunch of packages, settings so on and so forth.
Can you please provide a list of sorted items which has no duplicated stuff. I want to know what should I install and what is the order. I have tried other references and I know that one possible combination is:

```
teXnicCenter (Latex environment and Editor)
gsview 
pstotext 
pdfreader (viewer)
MikTex
...
```

but my list is not complete and I am not sure about which one to install first.

Comment: you might be looking for [proTeXt: easy-to-install TeX distribution for Windows, based on MiKTeX](https://www.tug.org/protext/) or  Crossplatform [TeXLive](https://www.tug.org/texlive/)

Comment: I don't think it is enough by itself.

Comment: It is enough. It contains MiKTeX and one editor (TeXWorks or TeXNicCenter). TeXWorks even has an integrated PDF viewer so don't need to install Adobe Reader just for this. `gsview` and `pstotext` is most likely unneeded.

Comment: Nobody can really tell you what to install without knowing your needs. On Windows, you have the option of either MikTeX or TeX Live. On any platform, you have the choice of a number of different editors and viewers. Which one you should install really depends on your needs and preferences. There's no 'right' or 'wrong' answer and you can always install a couple of editors and see which you like best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually **MiKTeX** alone should be enough. It contains

- all TeX and derivative programs you *may* need to run when LaTeXing (`tex pdftex latex xetex xelatex luatex lualatex makeindex bibtex biber texdoc` etc., together with documentation) but don't worry, this will mostly be taken care of by your editor.
- The TeXWorks editor. This is preconfigured so that hitting the green button in the top left corner will instantly typeset your PDF document.
- TeXWorks also has an integrated PDF viewer.
- Package manager. MiKTeX can automatically download all needed packages on-demand, so in the ideal case you won't need to open the package manager at all.